# Edited the question 3 times still not understand why it closed. Can I get help what else should I edit?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, closed-questions

About this question:
[How to measure how much time take took executing each line of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64006015/how-to-measure-how-much-time-take-took-executing-each-line-of-code?noredirect=1#comment113183571_64006015)

Is it not clear, or specific what I need?

Comment: Is this also part of the question: "I'm looking for a tool that will help me analyze and learn what make the app to be slow."?

Comment: This explaining the motivation why I need it. I'm trying to avoid the XY problem.

Comment: There is no way to fix it. You are looking for a tool (which probably does not exist, measuring performance "line by line" is not a generally useful or meaningful metric), and that's off-topic.

Comment: I mean, you could possibly edit it into asking how to use the Chrome devtools for a node application or how to read a flamechart but then it would most likely be a dupe of something.

Comment: You can try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is clear that you want someone to give you code that will do the hard part of instrumenting your code without you having to do any work. However, asking others to do that work is a bit broad, wouldn't you say? To do that in 30_000 characters? While explaining how the code works so that it's useful?

Answer (score 2):

You indicate in the comments that the part about you looking for a tool is not the question, it's just for context. That being said, it would help if you could be a little more clear about what your question is instead (so that people don't get confused and vote not to reopen for it being a tool rec question). For example, is there some information you need in order to be able to decide on a tool? If you could be a little more specific on that point, I think it would help greatly.